# How do higher-order functions like `map()` and `reduce()` receive their data?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write my own higher order function right now and I want to know how functions like `map()` and `reduce()` access the array they are being applied to. And not just for arrays either, but with *any* higher order function like `toString()` or `toLowerCase()`.

```
array.map()
^^^ // How do I get this data when I am writing my own higher order function?

array.myOwnFunction(/* data??? */)
```

I hope this makes sense. I'm sure the answer is out there already, but I'm struggling to know what to search for to find the information.

Comment: `Array.prototype.myOwnFunction()`. Inside the function `this` will refer to array itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it to the `Array` prototype like :

```js
Array.prototype.myOwnFunction = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i] += 1;
  }

  return this;
};

const array = [1, 2, 3];

const result = array.myOwnFunction();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the [polyfill for Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill), this line in particular:

```
//  1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
//    value as the argument.
var O = Object(this);
```

Simplifying, `this` is where the values are received.

Comment: is it just me or the link you provided is in Portuguese

Comment: @reg link fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the link! It's very interesting to see the source code for `map()`. Much simpler than I was expecting :)

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is related to the prototype and to the "thisBinding".

When a function is instantiated using `new`, the properties of the prototype are attached to the new Function object. As well, an "execution context" is created to maintain the environment. The properties of the prototype are then accessible in the environment through the current instance's this binding using `this`.

So if you have a function you want to use the data from in an instance, you can use a prototype as well. For many reasons (memory use, readability, reusability, inheritance, polymorphism, etc.) this is the best way to go about doing it. Modifying standard implementations such as `Array`, `Math`, `Date`, etc. are generally discouraged (although there will always be exceptions).

```js
function LineItem(description,price,quantity){
 this.description = description;
 this.price = price;
 this.quantity = quantity;
}
LineItem.prototype.Total = function(){
 return this.price * this.quantity;
};

var avocados = new LineItem("avocado",2.99,3);
console.log(avocados.Total());
```

The main thing to take away here is that the thisBinding allows access to the current instance's object through `this`. That is where the data access comes from. For example, in an array instance, this references the current array; in a date instance, this references the current date; in the above LineItem example, this references the current LineItem.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for sharing! I always wondered how `this` worked in that particular context.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the responses to this question I was able to write a higher order component that accepts a callback function as an argument. Here is the code as an example:

```js
Array.prototype.myFunction = function (callback) {
  const items = this
  const newArray = []
  for (let item of items) {
    item = callback(item)
    newArray.push(item)
  }
  return newArray
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const result = array.myFunction((item => {
  return item + 1
}))

console.log(result)
```